# what's the // @include in c++ comments

Tags: c++, c++11

I saw code like below

```
// @include
template <typename T>
      .....
// @exclude
```

Actually, I saw it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/elements-of-programming-interviews/source/browse/trunk/0-1_knapsack.cpp).

does the `@include`/`@exclude` have special meanings in the comment lines or is it only the author personal style?

Comment: Is this being built with some framework? Or pure C++?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything according to C++, but some other tool probably reads it.

Comment: It might be part of a Doxygen-based documentation tool?

Comment: The only thing that has special meaning in a comment in C++ is `*/` in a comment introduced by `/*`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has no special meaning in standard C++ and is probably part of some (documentation) tool that parses source files directly.

In particular, this is code from a book. The author may have chosen this syntax as a way to describe (and possibly automatically extract) what is in the book and what's not.